# Randomize loading order of products

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I am working on a site for a friend which is a site where she can sell her goods. I got the index view loading with the help of EF 6, MVC 5 and some people on here. Now I was wondering if there was a way to randomize the loading order so it's different each time. Here's is the code for the products control index method:

```
private AccessorizeForLessEntities entities = new AccessorizeForLessEntities();

// GET: /Products/
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var products = entities.Products.Include(p => p.ProductImage);

    IEnumerable<DisplayProductsViewModel> model = products.Select(p => new DisplayProductsViewModel()
    {
        Id = p.ProductId,
        Name = p.ProductName,
        Image = p.ProductImage,
        Price = p.ProductPrice.ToString()
    }).ToList();

    return View(model);
}
```

Is there a way I can alter this code to randomize the loading order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just order by something random. For example:

```
entities.Products.Include(p => p.ProductImage).OrderBy(o => Guid.NewGuid())
```